# Finding $E_4$ after minimizing $E_m$

Tags: physics

When approximating an even function with period $2\pi$ by a Fourier-cosine-Series with $m$ terms, it has the error
$$E_m=\int_{-\pi}^\pi \left[f(x)-\frac{a_0}{2}-\sum_{n=1}^m a_n \cos(nx)\right]^2 dx$$

Now I have to find the $a_n$'s which minimize this error.
I got to the point where:
$$a_n=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\cos(nx) dx$$

Now using a_n, E_m has to be minimized. Given that $$|\sin{x}|=\frac{2}{\pi}-\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos{2nx}}{4n^2-1}$$ for $$-\pi\leq x\leq\pi$$

I need to find $E_4$

I tried plugging in $a_n$ into $E_m$ but I don't know what $f(x)$ is.

Comment: Hi! It seems to be that you're trying to approximate $|\sin{x}|$, so that would be your $f(x)$, isn't it? In that case, you'd have to integrate $E_4$ plugging $|\sin{x}|$ into the first expression.

Comment: Hi! Well, f(x) is supposed to be an even function and sinx is odd so that's what I don't know

Comment: Ah, but $| \sin(x)|$ is even :)

Comment: oh, you're right, thanks!